# Is there a thematic train trip based on Christmas?

Tags: trains, where-on-earth

For some unknown reason to me trains and Christmas are related. There are movies about it and during Christmas I always see miniature trains and tracks being sold a lot more.

I enjoy traveling by train very much. I was wondering if there is a train trip somewhere where the theme is Christmas?

It's not a requirement at all, but if the trip is somehow near [one of these places](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22527/which-locations-are-traditionally-santas-home-i-e-where-can-you-visit-santa), that would be very nice.

Answer (score 5):

When I visited Santa in Rovaniemi, Finland, I took The Santa Claus Express from Helsinki, north to Rovaniemi.

[image: Santa Claus express]

(from [marksmayo.com](http://www.marksmayo.com/2011/07/06/the-santa-claus-train-from-helsinki-to-rovaniemi/))

[Description of my trip is on my blog, if you'd like to read more](http://www.marksmayo.com/2011/07/06/the-santa-claus-train-from-helsinki-to-rovaniemi/), although there weren't that many details, the train left daily at around 10pm in Helsinki, from memory.  It gets in 13 hours later.

The train itself wasn't terribly Christmas-y, aside from the name, but then I was in sitting class at the back - so perhaps it was nicer up front :)

Comment: The one time I took it (October 2010), I was in the first or second car (couchette) and I can confirm that it wasn’t christmas-y there either. It also did not look tremendously Christmas-y around Christmas that year (when I was trainspotting at Helsinki central). Seeing that there’s another night train route from Helsinki to the far North (Kolari) called *Aurora Borealis Express*, I think it’s just a name ;)